# How to convert datetime64 array to int?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

With this

```
pd.Timestamp("31.12.1999 23:59:12").value
>>946684752000000000
```

I can get the integer value of a datetime elementary value.

How can I get this done for an array of datetime values?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": ["31.12.1999 23:59:12", "31.12.1999 23:59:13", "31.12.1999 23:59:14"], "b": [4, 5, 6]})
df.insert(0, 'date', df.a.apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")))
```

Apparently, this does not work:

```
df.date.values.value
>>AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'value'
```

Comment: I'm confused about what you're trying to do. Why do you have `insert`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with converting to `np.int64`:

```
df['int'] = pd.to_datetime(df['a']).astype(np.int64)

print (df)
                     a  b                 int
0  31.12.1999 23:59:12  4  946684752000000000
1  31.12.1999 23:59:13  5  946684753000000000
2  31.12.1999 23:59:14  6  946684754000000000
```