# How can I mix Datetime & int features with Scikit learn?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, knn

I have a pandas DataFrame which looks like this:

```
                      pta                 ptd              dep_at
4     2020-01-08 05:17:00                 NaT                 NaT
6     2020-01-08 05:29:00 2020-01-08 05:30:00                 NaT
9     2020-01-08 05:42:00 2020-01-08 05:44:00 2020-01-08 05:44:00
11    2020-01-08 05:53:00 2020-01-08 05:54:00 2020-01-08 05:55:00
12    2020-01-08 06:03:00 2020-01-08 06:05:00 2020-01-08 06:04:00
```

And dtypes:

```
pta       datetime64[ns]
ptd       datetime64[ns]
dep_at    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

I'm using these to predict another column, `arr_at`, which is also `datetime64[ns]`. Running this works fine:

```
X = df[['pta','ptd','dep_at']]
y = df.arr_at
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3) # 70% training and 30% test
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5)
knn.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = knn.predict(X_test)
print("Accuracy:",metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
```

I'm trying to add another feature column, so my input now looks like this:

```
                   pta                 ptd              dep_at  tpl_num
4  2020-01-08 05:17:00                 NaT                 NaT        0
6  2020-01-08 05:29:00 2020-01-08 05:30:00                 NaT        1
9  2020-01-08 05:42:00 2020-01-08 05:44:00 2020-01-08 05:44:00        2
11 2020-01-08 05:53:00 2020-01-08 05:54:00 2020-01-08 05:55:00        3
12 2020-01-08 06:03:00 2020-01-08 06:05:00 2020-01-08 06:04:00        4
```

(and dtypes):

```
pta        datetime64[ns]
ptd        datetime64[ns]
dep_at     datetime64[ns]
tpl_num             int64
dtype: object
```

But now, when I run the same KNN code as before, only changing

```
X = df[['pta','ptd','dep_at']]
```

to

```
X = df[['pta','ptd','dep_at','tpl_num']]
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Timestamp'
```

I can't figure out what'd going wrong. It might be of note that I add the column to the feature data by doing this, although I'm pretty sure this isn't affecting anything:

```
#Map station names in csv to ints, using dictionary comprehension
tpl_class = {k: v for v, k in enumerate(df.tpl.unique())}
#Apply to data
df['tpl_num'] = [tpl_class[i] for i in df.tpl]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this occures as you now have mixed types in your knn.

A workaround for would be to convert your datetime[ns] to an [integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52024899/how-to-convert-datetime64-array-to-int) (e.g. for one column):

```
df['pta'] = pd.to_datetime(df['pta']).astype(np.int64)
```

Include that for all datetime columns before you pick your X and then it should work.